# How to fix TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, typeerror

I am trying to solve a very easy challenge about finding the longest word in a string. 
This is the code:

```
function find(par) {
    let arrayWord = par.split(" ");
    let longestWord = "";
    for (let i = 0; i <= arrayWord.length; i++) {
        if (longestWord.length < arrayWord[i].length) {
            longestWord = arrayWord[i]
        }
    }
    return longestWord;
}
find("Find the longest word");
```

I would need help understanding why I am getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
>       at find (:5:47)
>       at :11:1 find @ VM959:5 (anonymous) @ VM959:11

thank you.

Comment: When `i == arrayWord.length`, what is the value of `arrayWord[i]`?

Comment: You're going one iteration to far (`i <= arrayWord.length`), you need to change `<=` to `<`

Comment: Consider an array of one value, if `arrayWord = ['hello']`. Its length is 1. Your loop goes until (and including) when `i == 1`, but what then is `arrayWord[1]`? There is only `arrayWord[0]` -- `arrayWord[1]` is undefined and so its length is trying to be the length of an undefined variable, which errors.

Comment: man length is undefined, u must check array list

Comment: @RobG I was thinking to transform the string passed in the function into an array separating each word as individual elements, then checking if the length of each element in the arrayWord is bigger than the longestWord.

Comment: @NickParsons, well that completely solved my problem, thank you.

Comment: @IceMetalPunk, thank you I totally understood now. I didn't take into consideration that the last item of an array is = array.length - 1, therefore adding a = next to the < would iterate for another element that is not in the array.

Comment: @chandukomati so if I understood it right, the error length is undefined it is because I try to retrieve the length of a nonexisting array element (which in this case is given by the = operator next to the < operator)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cannot read property 'length' of undefined comes when it is not able to find variable of certain type(In your case a string) to call the function length. In your case arrayWord[i].length is not a proper string for the last condition of your check as there is no element arrayWord[arrayWord.length] present in the array. That's why arrayWord[i].length is giving you an error for your last iteration. Just change i <= arrayWord.length to i < arrayWord.length

```
function find(par) {
  let arrayWord = par.split(" ");
  let longestWord = "";
  for (let i = 0; i <arrayWord.length; i++) {
    if (longestWord.length < arrayWord[i].length) {
      longestWord = arrayWord[i]
    }
  }
  return longestWord;
}
```

Edits: Changes made as suggested by RobG

Comment: This answer is confusing. "*par.split(" ") is not able to create an array*" is wrong, *split* **always** returns an array. "*That's why array.length is giving you an error*" no, it's not. *arrayWord* will always be an array provided *par* is a string. The issue is attempting to access `arrayWord[i]` when `i == arrayWord.length`, it will **always** be undefined (because *length* is always at least 1 greater than the last index in the array).

Answer (score 2):

### Just change condition <= to < and try

```js
function find(par) {
    let arrayWord = par.split(" ");
    let longestWord = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < arrayWord.length; i++) {
        if (longestWord.length < arrayWord[i].length) {
            longestWord = arrayWord[i]
        }
    }
    return longestWord;
}

console.log(find("Find the longest word"));
```

Comment: A good answer should explain why the OP has their issue and how your code fixes it.